# Access response from jQuery.get() or jQuery.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get the response from a file using `$.get()`

```
$.get('filename.svg', function (response) {
    console.log(response);

    return response;
});
```

When I log response I see something like this

```
#document
    <svg ...>
        <g>....</g>
    </svg>
```

I wanted to ask how I could access a **#document**? property. and print `<svg></svg>` tag without `#document`

To clarify what I need that exactly for.
I need to calculate SVG size using `getBBox()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$.ajax()` and supply `dataType` to be `text`

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'filename.svg',
        dataType: 'text'
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) This does the job :)